# Error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, virtualbox

I got this error message when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 using the latest version of Oracle VirtualBox. I tried to launch Ubuntu 20.04 several times, but I was unable to open it.

[image]

Comment: That does not look like an Ubuntu-related problem. It looks like you made a mistake when setting up the VM. Go back to whatever instructions you were following and do them again more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall VirtualBox's Extension Pack, then uninstall VirtualBox. Restart your computer. Right-click the VirtualBox installer and choose *Run as Administrator*. Do not install the VirtualBox Extension Pack for now. Reboot Windows again.